# removing tweets containing hyperlinks using twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

while using the twitteR package for sentiment analysis of an e-commerce site, I have noticed that most of the tweets that I get are about offers and sales. They always have a hyperlink, and if I can ignore those tweets in my input feed, I can get more tweets from consumers whose sentiment I want to gauge. While I can leave these tweets out while refining my data, it results in a very small dataset to work with. Is there any way I could do that during the search itself? My aim is to get a big enough dataset containing customer tweets to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Although I did not understand your question clearly, if you just want to remove URLs from your data using twitteR package, this may help

```
removeURL <- function (x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
myCorpus  <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)
```

Comment: I want to filter the input tweets such that tweets containing URLs are excluded. i.e. if I query for say, 1000 tweets, I want to get back from the twitter api, 1000 tweets which do not contain any URLs.

Comment: From what I've read in the Twitter REST API documentation and in package manuals for things like twitteR, there is no way to do this. You can only filter the URL-free tweets after you have requested them.

Comment: Sorry @srikterdon Do late reply, you may already got the ans.I found it will not be possible what you want to do. Why not do another thing, from your dataset if words contain like www or https:// , delete the entire row.  how Does that sound

Comment: @Noah , your suggestion is perhaps the only workable way to filter the dataset, but it results in about 85-90 % of the data being filtered. The resulting dataset is too small to be of significance. Repeating the search does not help, as we end up getting more or less the same dataset.

Comment: @Srikterdon , technology still helpless ; best of luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot properly ask the API for 'tweets that don't contain links'. Find what those tweets have in common, say '**Etrans**: I just bought X http://...' and filter them out in your later queries via 'querysubject -Etrans'.

Comment: have filtered atleast 10 such queryobjects, but it does not improve the feed. I have managed to get only about 75 consumer tweets out of 1000, hence the requirement to filter at the API itself.